# 1.Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'user1' has already been declared . 2 and not return updated values

Tags: javascript

```js
function creatUser(name, score = 0) {
  let user = {};
  user.name = `Amir`;
  user.score = 0;
  user.increaseScore = function (value = 1) {
    user.score = user.score + value;
    return user.score;
  };
  user.decreaseScore = function (value = 1) {
    user.score = user.score - value;
    return user.score;
  };
  user.changeName = function (name) {
    user.name = name;
    return user.name;
  };
  return user;
}
let user1 = creatUser(`Sameer`, 20);
let user2 = creatUser(`Zoya`);
```

> Blockquote
> when I access user1 it will go through an error `user1 alreay defined` and when I access user2 then it will not retrun updated values.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. As you can see by clicking the "*run code snippet*" button in your post, the code does not throw an exception.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , the code is working well
and secondly you should use class for doing this !